# View Compressed Image or encoded image ..?

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, image, image-processing

**I need to view image ..**

the image file without extension

Like (.jpeg , .TIF ,.TIFF....etc) and this image is scanned from scanner also it's white and black image *"microcosmic image* " .
it might be encoded and compressed .
**i knew that is [PKZIP](https://www.pkware.com/software/pkzip/windows) tool is used to encode or decode or for compression .so i tried but not reach for result .**
[image file upload over my google drive.](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B39UUO25HVKnczBrUlpfUEh3bmc/edit)

Comment: i need ti view the image file as possible as can ?
please any help ... as fast as can ...???

Answer (score -1):

***Try Matlab solution LZW & LZ77.***

Comment: i use matlab but is not commercial solution :(